# How to import module into jsx?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, module, jsx

Using jsx/react and trying to import a function from another file. This is my jsx:

```
import React from 'react';
import {sayHello} from './stuff'

export class Arrow extends React.Component {

  cb = () => { // the class property is initialized with an arrow function that binds this to the class
console.log('testing=cb clicked')
  }

  render() {
    console.log('testing=sayHello()',sayHello() )
    return (
      <button onClick={ this.cb }>Click</button>
    );
  }
}
```

Trying to import the sayHello that looks like this:

```
const sayHello = () => 'say hello'

export default sayHello
```

When I run the jsx I get this error:

```
Uncaught Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, `import {sayHello} from ...` should be `import sayHello from ...`. Second, just because you made that first mistake, ensure that you are importing your `Arrow` component using `import {Arrow} from ...` instead of `import Arrow from ...`, because the former works and the latters produces several errors for me, including the one that you mention.

Comment: It worked but why do I have to use {} with Arrow and not with sayHello?

Comment: With `export class Arrow...` you have to use `import {Arrow}...` whereas with `export default class Arrow...` you have to use `import Arrow...`. In the former case, there might be multiple `export...` statements in a file and therefore your import statement has to be able to handle importing multiple variables by placing that potential list of variables in braces. With `export default...` there can be only a single export from that file and therefore the import statement can confidently assert that it is importing a single variable, i.e. `import myVariable...`.